# Problem with 'for in' loop over arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, for-in-loop

Today I faced with a problem and I fixed it but I didn't know why it occurs! So I decided to ask it here.

Let me show my problem fast and short:

```js
function newProp(array) {
  let returnArray = [];
  for (i in array) {
    returnArray.push(i);
  }
  return returnArray;
}

let underTest = [{
  username: 'stackoverflow',
  email: 'stackoverflow@noStack.com',
  total: 2
}]
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (i in underTest) {
  console.log('before call:', underTest[i]);
  underTest[i].permutation = newProp(input);
  console.log('after call the underTest[i] does not exist:', underTest[i]);
  console.log('But the whole array still exists', underTest);
}
```

**Code Explanation:** I'm trying to add a new property called `permutation` to each object of `underTest` array.

**Problem:** I don't expect the `underTest[i]` be `undefined` after calling `newProp()` function.

**My Question:** Why `underTest[i]` is `undefined` after calling `newProp()`? I think it's because of using `for in` over array in my code but in [MDN web doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) there is no hint about my problem, it just says:

> Note: for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the
> index order is important.
>
> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and
> are otherwise identical to general object properties. There is no
> guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular
> order. The for...in loop statement will return all enumerable
> properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are
> inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation-dependent, iterating
> over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore,
> it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or
> Array.prototype.forEach() or the for...of loop) when iterating over
> arrays where the order of access is important.

and due to above paragraphs while I don't mind the order of elements I should be able to use `for in` structure(I don't mind the inherited properties too).

**Solutions:**
By trial and error, I found so many solutions to solve the problem and I think it's useful to mention some of them:

1. Replace `for in` with a traditional `for` loop will solve the problem:

```js
function newProp(array) {
  let returnArray = [];
  for (i in array) {
    returnArray.push(i);
  }
  return returnArray;
}

let underTest = [{
  username: 'stackoverflow',
  email: 'stackoverflow@noStack.com',
  total: 2
}]
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let i = 0; i < underTest.length; i++) {
  console.log('before call:', underTest[i]);
  underTest[i].permutation = newProp(input);
  console.log('after call the underTest[i] exists', underTest[i]);
}
```

2. In `newProp` functions, If Instead of making the array dynamically, return an static array then the problem disappears(I didn't know why, yet!):

```js
function newProp(array) {
  return [1, 2, 3, 4];
}

let underTest = [{
  username: 'stackoverflow',
  email: 'stackoverflow@noStack.com',
  total: 2
}]
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (i in underTest) {
  console.log('before call:', underTest[i]);
  underTest[i].permutation = newProp(input);
  console.log('after call the underTest[i] exists', underTest[i]);
}
```

3. you can use built-in `forEach` method of `underTest` array and it will solve the problem too but I didn't like it because it can leads to *callback hell* problem(especially if you work with asynchronous jobs). So I didn't provide its snippet.

**NOTE:** If you can, please explain why the second solution will solve the problem too?

Comment: Your `i` is global which you continually overwrite, this after you call `newProp`, it will have the last value it had after the loop in that function. Just declare it, so it's not implicitly global.

Comment: You need to add `let`: `for (let i in underTest)`

Comment: Normally we use ```for...in``` for objects and not for arrays.. Some people considering it as a bad practice to use it for array.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/7785337

Comment: @VLAZ
Thank you both of you I even couldn't imagine my problem was so simple.

Comment: @HaoWu Thank you, I even couldn't imagine my problem was so simple

Comment: @ManirajMurugan this is no problem to use it here, read my complete question

Comment: @milad, I am not complaining anything about your question.. It is fine.. But coming to best practice its recommended to use ```for...in``` only for objects..

Comment: Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @ManirajMurugan you're right, I'll try to avoid it next times. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @HaoWu and @VLAZ commented, My problem is not related to `for in` loop. It's because of declaring the `i` variables as global.

if I change the declaration of `i` variables to local the problem will disappear:

```js
function newProp(array) {
  let returnArray = [];
  for (let i in array) {
    returnArray.push(i);
  }
  return returnArray;
}

let underTest = [{
  username: 'stackoverflow',
  email: 'stackoverflow@noStack.com',
  total: 2
}]
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let i in underTest) {
  console.log('before call:', underTest[i]);
  underTest[i].permutation = newProp(input);
  console.log('after call the underTest[i] exists:', underTest[i]);
}
```

**Updates:**

As @3limin4t0r mentioned below this answer: if you don't need the index of elements it's better to use `for of` structure instead of `for in`:

```js
function newProp(array) {
  let returnArray = [];
  for (let i in array) {
    returnArray.push(i);
  }
  return returnArray;
}

let underTest = [{
  username: 'stackoverflow',
  email: 'stackoverflow@noStack.com',
  total: 2
}]
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let element of underTest) {
  console.log('before call:', element);
  element.permutation = newProp(input);
  console.log('after call the underTest[i] exists:', element);
}
```

Comment: You also don't need an `i` if you where to use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate arrays.

Comment: Why use `for in` at all. I have hard time finding a reason why to use it in general. Use ES6 `forEach` or `map` instead.

Comment: @3limin4t0r You're right. but this code is a simplified version of main code in a big project which we need the index of each element later too. but if there was no need to indexes of elements I prefer to use the `for...of` too.

Comment: @MaxFavilli unfortunately `forEach` and `map` doesn't support `ansyc` functions as callback: if you should `await` to some asynchronous jobs in your callback you should define the callback as `async`  but then the order of elements is almost random(so you couldn't find when the callback finishes). By the way the best solution to fix this, is using `map` and `Promise.all` together which is out of context here.